# vpn with internet explorer domain

Tags: internet-explorer, sharepoint-2010, vpn

I am trying to access a sharepoint site through VPN with Internet Explorer. I have a login, but when I am trying to to input my credentials it rejects it because the domain is set to domain.local and I am logging as my own computer. 
I can easily login to the VPN itself, but I cannot access SP.
Chrome works fine

What am I doing wrong?

I am using Network Connect

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved! Had to set domain/user in username!